# Absolute Positioning of Text in a Dynamically Sized SVG

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

I have an SVG graphic that I want to put some text on from my PHP variables. The graphic was generated in Illustrator and resizes in my web page to 100% width. Here is a representation of it:

[image]

How could this be done for the 8 text items? Does something special need to be done in Illustrator, like creating an anchor point for the text? How do I update the text item? I've done research but haven't been able to find a similar situation.

Thankful for any information that could help me narrow down my search.

Comment: <svg> element should receive the width and heights attributes explicitly. 

Put <svg> inside a <div> and obtain the <div> size in the run-time to pass them to the <svg>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being someone who has never worked with files of .SVG file type before, this was a misunderstanding.

If you design a graphic in Adobe Illustrator, save it as an SVG and edit it with your favorite text editor, you will be able to see the SVG mark-up. It all makes sense now, and here you will be able to change the text at the code-level.

For my application, I saved the SVG as a PHP file and did an include on it, while changing the raw text to PHP variables in said file. This allowed me to pass my dynamic text as variables to the graphic.